# Simple spacer in buttons and search bar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to insert a Label, Search bar, Button group in a Panel Heading.

I have the following code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="label label-default">
<%= yield(:title) %>
</span>
  <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
<% if can? :create, Client %>
<%= link_to 'New', new_client_path %>
<% end %>
</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
<div class="input-group col-lg-3 pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
<div id="clients"><%= render 'clients' %></div>
<p class="small"><%= will_paginate @clients %></p>
</div>
```

As of now it works, but search bar and button group have no space between them. I would like to have ateast 5px space between them so like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Label                                   Search -space- btn group
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to achieve this?
I am using Rails 4 with Sass

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question better we would need to know what CSS you are using. Guessing I suggest adding a `DIV` around your search input and add a class with a display: inline-block and then add a right padding.

```
<div class="mycustclass">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>

.mycustclass {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

You would also need your `.input-group-btn` class to use a `display:inline-block` as well.

If that doesn't work there are plenty of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Just write margin-right:5px in first btn-primary inline than it will be work
not write padding-right

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></button>
</div>
```